# Copying lists in python

Tags: python, list, function, random

I am relatively new to Python.
I am trying to come up with a function that takes a list, adds +1 to a value at random in that list, and then places a new list with the modified value as a new index.

For instance, if I have

```
blank=[]
list_one=[1,2,3,4,5] #
```

The possible outcome might be

```
blank=[ [1,2,3,4,5], [1,3,3,4,5],[1,3,3,4,6],[2,3,3,4,6],[2,4,3,4,6] ]
```

So the function takes blank[0], copies and modifies it, and returns it as blank[1]. Similarly, the function takes blank[1], copies it and modifies it, and returns it as blank[2]

This is my code:

```
import random
list_one=[1,2,3,4,5]
def new_function(value):
    for i in range(1,value):
        list_copy=list_one[:]
        blank.append(list_copy)
        x=random.choice(blank[i])
        y=blank[i].index(x)
        blank[i][y]=x+1
    return blank

print new_function(4) 
"""Yields [ [1,2,3,4,5],[1,3,3,4,5],[2,2,3,4,5],[1,2,4,4,5] ] 
   (this is the list, blank)"""
```

my problem is that blank[1], blank[2], and blank[3] are all modifications of blank[0], when each indexed list should be a modification of the previous indexed list.

What am I doing wrong here???

Comment: As a note, I've always found using `list(seq)` to copy lists much nicer to read than `seq[:]`. The latter can be a bit cryptic to new users, and they are equivalent.

Comment: Okay thanks for the info. But why is my function just creating modified copies of the first list in blank?

Comment: Blank[1] has to be a modified copy of blank[0], blank[2] has to be a modified copy of blank[1], and so on. But my function just copies blank[0] each time and modifies a value at random

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that you always copy the original list, not the new one. This is easily solved by using the same name for the new list, thus, when the loop comes round again, the new list is copied:

```
import random

def randomly_increment(seq, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        x = random.randrange(len(seq))
        seq = list(seq)
        seq[x] += 1
        yield seq
```

Which I believe works as intended:

```
>>> list(randomly_increment([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4))
[[1, 2, 4, 4, 5], [1, 2, 4, 5, 5], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 4, 6, 6]]
```

Other changes:

- Rather than building a list, this is a generator, which is generally more flexible and easier to read/write. If you need a list, then wrap the call with `list()` as above.
- Rather than making a random choice, then finding it's place to change it, it makes more sense to pick a place, and change it. This also avoids the issue where `seq.index()` will return the first value matching the given one, not necessarily the 'picked' one.
- Using `list(seq)` to copy over `seq[:]`, as noted in my comment. This is more readable.

Comment: Ohh okay I see. I guess that was my problem after all!

And thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You start your range from `1`, when they should start from 0, Also, you always copy from `list_one` and never update it, hence they are all copies of the original list, and not the previously modified one, here's the fixed code

```
import random
list_one=[1,2,3,4,5]
blank = []
def new_function(value):
    global list_one
    for i in range(value):
        list_copy = list_one[:]
        blank.append(list_copy)
        x=random.choice(blank[i])
        y=blank[i].index(x)
        blank[i][y]=x+1
        list_one = list_copy
    return blank
print new_function(4)
```

This gave me a random output of

```
[[2, 2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 2, 3, 4, 6], [3, 2, 3, 5, 6]]
```

which matches your description.

Also, instead of choosing an element from the list, why not choose a random index and then modify it?

```
def new_function(value):
    global list_one
    for i in range(value):
        list_copy=list_one[:]
        blank.append(list_copy)
        x=random.randrange(len(list_copy))
        blank[i][x] += 1
        list_one = list_copy
    return blank
```

Answer (score 0):

To be sure to copy the list each time I would go something like this:

```py
from random import choice
list_one=[1,2,3,4,5]

def new_function(value):

    blank=[]
    blank.append(list_one)

    new_list = []

    for i in range(value):
        new_list = new_list[:] if new_list else list_one[:]
        new_list[choice(new_list)] += 1 
        blank.append(new_list)
    return blank

print (new_function(4))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. My interpreter says that 'list' object has no attribute 'copy'

Comment: I'm running Python 3.3, anyway I corrected the snippet to use list slice.